# how to upload and save a file with desired name php

Tags: php, forms, upload

I want to upload and save a file with variable name in my root directory inside the project folder this code below is what i tried but when i go to that folder there is no file in there

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit_student'])){
    $student_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($cnn,$_POST['student_id']);
    $exam_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($cnn,$_POST['exam_id']);

echo " <form action='manage_add_result.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
echo "  <input type='file' name='resultpdf'><br>";
echo "  <input type='hidden' name='exam_id' value=\"{$exam_id}\">";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='student_id' value=\"{$student_id}\">";
echo "<input type='submit' name='upload_btn' value='upload'>";
echo "</form>";
}
 ?>
 <?php 

 if (isset($_POST['upload_btn'])){
 if(isset($_FILES['resultpdf']['name'])){
 $newname=mysqli_real_escape_string($cnn,$_POST['student_id']) . "_".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['exam_id']) . ".pdf";
 $target='karname/'."{$newname}";
  move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['resultpdf']['tmp_name'] , $target);

 }


 }

 ?>
```

I am wondering what should i do

Comment: You should start by adding some `else` blocks to your `if`s and see which of the conditions fail. Then try to find out *why* they fail. Also, check the return value of `move_uploaded_file`. And, maybe you need to activate or increase your error reporting.

Comment: So, all of the `if`s were successful, and `move_uploaded_file` returned `true`? Have you tried dumping the `$target` variable? What's the output of `echo realpath($target)`?

Comment: Check out the chmod of your karname/ folder

Comment: it say's to me that the upload-button is not set

Comment: It's probably because you have two seperated sets of code. You should place your HTML form outside of PHP using a standard HTML method without echos, then placing your entire PHP/SQL inside `<?php ... ?>` - Plus, you do not have a form element called `submit_student` that is the most important reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you do not have a form element named `submit_student` that is why part of your code does not work, as per this conditional statement `if (isset($_POST['submit_student']))`

Try the following:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['upload_btn'])){
    $student_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($cnn,$_POST['student_id']);
    $exam_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($cnn,$_POST['exam_id']);


    if(isset($_FILES['resultpdf']['name'])){
    $newname=mysqli_real_escape_string($cnn,$_POST['student_id']) . "_".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['exam_id']) . ".pdf";
    $target='karname/'."{$newname}";
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['resultpdf']['tmp_name'] , $target);
    }


    echo " <form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
    echo "  <input type='file' name='resultpdf'><br>";
    echo "  <input type='hidden' name='exam_id' value=\"{$exam_id}\">";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='student_id' value=\"{$student_id}\">";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='upload_btn' value='upload'>";
    echo "</form>";
    }
?>
```

Plus, since you are executing everything from the same file you can just do `action=""` instead of `action='manage_add_result.php'`

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help during production testing.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: i have 3 forms in that page which is like this : the second form will be generated by first form and the third form will generated by second form how can i handle this ?

Comment: @MortezaAzmoodehafshar That I don't know how Morteza.